# How to set value of a property that's a custom object

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to keep track of which sprite a user has dragged/dropped on top of the "Rectangle" objects.  I thought the easiest thing to do would be to add a property of the same type "MySprite" to the "Rectangle" objects and then set it's value equal to the "MySprite" that's been dropped on top of it.  I thought using the property "MySprite *sprite" in the "Rectangle.h" file along with synthesizing it in the "Retangle.m" file would have automatically created the "setSprite" method.  I'm not understanding something....

The "target.sprite = selSprite;" line of code below in the CocosScene.m causes the following error:

2013-05-14 20:32:51.953 DragDrop[461:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CCSprite setSprite:]: **unrecognized selector sent to instance** 0x8d5c280'

### Rectangle.h

```
#import "CCNode.h"
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "MySprite.h"

@interface Rectangle : CCNode
{
    MySprite *sprite;
}

@property(nonatomic,readwrite,copy) MySprite *sprite;

@end
```

### Rectangle.m

```
@implementation Rectangle

@synthesize sprite = _sprite;

@end
```

### CocosScene.m

```
for(Rectangle *target in wordCircleRectangles)
            {

                if(CGRectIntersectsRect(selSprite.boundingBox, target.boundingBox))
                {
                    target.sprite = selSprite;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Assuming the error is from the line `target.sprite = selSprite` then the error indicates that `target` is not really a `Rectangle` object but is in fact a `CCSprite` object. You need to verify what objects you are putting in `wordCircleRectangles`.

Comment: You're right rmaddy.  I'd like to give you the credit for answering the question, but since it's a comment, I can't.  Thank you.